# How to disable modifying workitems in YouTrack workflows?

Tags: javascript, youtrack

I want to prevent users in YouTrack from **modifying** or **adding** **workitems** in the *past*. They should only add/modify workitems in *current* day.

In YouTrack workflows i can detect changed **Spent time event** and prevent users from **adding** workitem. But I want to get an event when **user is modifying workitem** in JavaScript workflows. Here is my code:

```
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var workflow = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/workflow');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({

  title: workflow.i18n('Disable editing workitems'),

  guard: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.issue.fields.isChanged(ctx.ST);
  },

  action: function(ctx) {
    workflow.check(ctx.issue.workItems.added.isEmpty(), workflow.i18n('You can add/modify workitems only in current day.'));
  },

  requirements: {
    ST: {
      type: entities.Field.periodType,
      name: 'Spent Time'
    }
  }
});
```

Datetime conditions are omitted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its still relevant, but I have full example:

```
/**
 * This is a template for an on-change rule. This rule defines what
 * happens when a change is applied to an issue.
 *
 * For details, read the Quick Start Guide:
 * https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/2022.2/Quick-Start-Guide-Workflows-JS.html
 */

const entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
const workflow = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/workflow');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: 'Prevent-workitem-updates-past',
  guard: (ctx) => {
    const issue = ctx.issue;
    const fs = issue.fields;
    
    // NOT using issue.workItems.added.isEmpty() , because we also want to detect EDITS as well as ADDS to the WorkItems array.
    return fs.isChanged(ctx.ST) && !issue.becomesReported;
  },
  action: (ctx) => {
    const issue = ctx.issue;
   
    function checkWorkItemDate(currentWorkItem, currentEpochTimeStamp){
        workflow.check(currentWorkItem.date == currentEpochTimeStamp, workflow.i18n('You can add/modify workitems only in current day.'));
    }

    //const splittedDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-');
    //const currentEpoch = new Date(splittedDate[0], splittedDate[1] - 1, splittedDate[2]).valueOf();

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentEpoch = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()).valueOf();
     
    // Check newly added elements
    issue.workItems.added.forEach(workItem => {
        checkWorkItemDate(workItem, currentEpoch);
    });
    
    // Check edited elements
    issue.editedWorkItems.forEach(workItem => {
        checkWorkItemDate(workItem, currentEpoch);
    });
    
    workflow.check(true);
  },
  requirements: {
    ST: {
      type: entities.Field.periodType,
      name: 'Spent Time'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for ctx.issue.workItems.isChanged and also check the content of ctx.issue.editedWorkItems set.